# How can i redirect to a new page after login is successful with php

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

thank you for your consideration.
I'll be short and concise, because it seems i get banned no matter what i post.
I found similar questions on here but none of the suggestions were working with my code.

i just need help after login is successful redirecting to a new page my code is.

```
 $username = $_POST["username"]; 

    $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);


    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '" .$username.  "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "Password Entered: " . $_POST["password"];
        echo "Correct Pasword: " . $row['password'];

        // See if the password is correct
        if ($_POST["password"] === $row['password'])
            echo "Logon Successful!";


        else {
            echo "Logon Failed!";
        }
    }
     if (!mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        echo "Invalid Username";
?>
```

Comment: Like a normal redirect? Maybe the header('Location: http://sitetoberedirect.com'); function can help you
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Thank you for your help, It states that it must be called before any output is sent. i'm very new to php was wondering how i can use this in an if else statement

Comment: There are several method to deal with redirecting. One of them is to seperate **login logic** and **output data**. You can keep output data in sessions or cookies and show them after redirected the other page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a bit of changes like the following:

### login.php

```
$username = $_POST["username"]; 
$password = $_POST["password"];
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '" . $username .  "'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    // See if the password is correct
    if ($password === $row['password']){
        header('location: login_successful.php');
    }else {
        // you can hide the message at QueryString via SESSION or COOKIE
        header('location: login_form.php?message=FAIL_MESSAGE');  //you can detect and show login status message.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i just forgot a semicolon after the header..

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '" .$username.  "'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    // See if the password is correct
    if  ($_POST["password"] === $row['password']){
        echo "Logon Successful!";
        header("Location: index.php"); 
        exit();
    }
```